# Streaming to a mediaelement

Tags: windows-phone-7, vlc

I'm playing around with streaming to a simple mediaelement in silverlight from VLC, but i'm having no such luck. I'm using the following code;

mediaelement.Source = new Uri("http://localip:8080", UriKind.Absolute);
mediaelement.play();

On the VLC end i'm using the following video settings (which i believe WP supports)
Method: HTTP
Container: MP4
Video: H-264
Audio: MP3

All i get is a black screen, no error, no video and no sound. I've read that WP doesnt like playing media etc whilst zune is running, so i've ran the project with my phone connected using wpconnect instead but still have the same issue.

Can anyone give me a few tips?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

[See this article for configuration and compatible audio and video formats](http://diaconu13.blogspot.com/2010/07/live-streaming-in-silverlight-4.html):

From this article:

> http://ipaddress:port;stream.nsv :sout=#transcode
>   vcodec=WMV2,vb=5000,fps=30,scale=1,acodec=wma2,ab=128,channels=1,samplerate=44100}:std{access=mmsh,mux=asfh,dst=MyIP:PortNo}
>   :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :sout-keep

Comment: thanks for the link, although i'm still not getting anything to play. I use the example of setting the source property in the link you provided and then issue the play(). But still getting nothing. Perhaps it's i have to do something different with Windows Phone?

Comment: Wondering if this has anything to do with it? http://forums.silverlight.net/post/351209.aspx

Comment: Is the Phone connected to the local network using USB or Wifi?

Comment: It's been both, tested the deployed app running on just the phone too.

Comment: Have you tried navigating the WP7 browser to the stream? See the post at `19th June 2011, 04:57 PM` in this thread: http://forum.xda-developers.com/archive/index.php/t-892906.html